# VHDL Code for State Machine

Tags: vhdl, adc

I am attempting to write a Successive Approximation Register in VHDL for an ADC. I am making it a state machine. I am just a little unsure about my code in the final State block (current_state = S_LSB). Is this code valid? Is there a better way to reset DigitalOutTemp and OutTemp before going back to state one?

**NOTE** The value  of Comparator depends on the DigitalOutTemp output after it goes through a Digital to Analog Converter.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE     ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY SARegister IS
PORT (
    Comparator, Clock                     : IN std_logic;
    DigitalOutFinal, DigitalOutTemp   : OUT std_logic_vector (13 downto 0)
);
END;

ARCHITECTURE Behavioural OF SARegister IS

CONSTANT S_MSB      : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0000";
CONSTANT S_TWELVE   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0001";
CONSTANT S_ELEVEN   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0010";
CONSTANT S_TEN      : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0011";
CONSTANT S_NINE     : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0100";
CONSTANT S_EIGHT    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0101";
CONSTANT S_SEVEN    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0110";
CONSTANT S_SIX      : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0111";
CONSTANT S_FIVE     : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "1000";
CONSTANT S_FOUR     : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "1001";
CONSTANT S_THREE    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "1010";
CONSTANT S_TWO      : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "1011";
CONSTANT S_ONE      : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "1100";
CONSTANT S_LSB      : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "1101";

SIGNAL Next_state       : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL Current_state    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL OutTemp          : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(13 DOWNTO 0);    

BEGIN

PROCESS (Clock)
BEGIN

    IF (rising_edge (Clock)) THEN       
        Current_state <= Next_state;
    END IF;

END PROCESS;

PROCESS (Current_state, Comparator)
BEGIN
    Next_state <= Current_state;
    DigitalOutTemp <= "10000000000000";
    OutTemp <= "10000000000000";
    DigitalOutFinal <= "00000000000000";

    IF (Current_state = S_MSB) THEN
        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN 
            DigitalOutTemp(13) <= '0';
            OutTemp(13) <= '0';
        END IF;
        DigitalOutTemp(12) <='1';
        OutTemp(12) <= '1';
        Next_state <= S_TWELVE;

    ELSIF (Current_state = S_TWELVE) THEN
        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN 
            DigitalOutTemp(12) <= '0';
            OutTemp(12) <= '0';
        END IF;
        DigitalOutTemp(11) <='1';
        OutTemp(11) <= '1';
        Next_state <= S_ELEVEN;

    ELSIF (Current_state = S_ELEVEN) THEN
        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN 
            DigitalOutTemp(11) <= '0';
            OutTemp(11) <= '0';
        END IF;
        DigitalOutTemp(10) <='1';
        OutTemp(10) <= '1';         
        Next_state <= S_TEN;

    ELSIF (Current_state = S_TEN) THEN
        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN 
            DigitalOutTemp(10) <= '0';
            OutTemp(10) <= '0';
        END IF;
        DigitalOutTemp(9) <='1';
        OutTemp(9) <= '1';          
        Next_state <= S_NINE;

    ELSIF (Current_state = S_NINE) THEN
        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN 
            DigitalOutTemp(9) <= '0';
            OutTemp(9) <= '0';
        END IF;
        DigitalOutTemp(8) <='1';
        OutTemp(8) <= '1';          
        Next_state <= S_EIGHT;

    ELSIF (Current_state = S_EIGHT) THEN
        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN 
            DigitalOutTemp(8) <= '0';
            OutTemp(8) <= '0';
        END IF;
        DigitalOutTemp(7) <='1';
        OutTemp(7) <= '1';          
        Next_state <= S_SEVEN;

    ELSIF (Current_state = S_SEVEN) THEN
        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN 
            DigitalOutTemp(7) <= '0';
            OutTemp(7) <= '0';
        END IF;
        DigitalOutTemp(6) <='1';
        OutTemp(6) <= '1';          
        Next_state <= S_SIX;

    ELSIF (Current_state = S_SIX) THEN
        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN 
            DigitalOutTemp(6) <= '0';
            OutTemp(6) <= '0';
        END IF;
        DigitalOutTemp(5) <='1';
        OutTemp(5) <= '1';          
        Next_state <= S_FIVE;

    ELSIF (Current_state = S_FIVE) THEN
        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN 
            DigitalOutTemp(5) <= '0';
            OutTemp(5) <= '0';
        END IF;
        DigitalOutTemp(4) <='1';
        OutTemp(4) <= '1';          
        Next_state <= S_FOUR;

    ELSIF (Current_state = S_FOUR) THEN
        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN 
            DigitalOutTemp(4) <= '0';
            OutTemp(4) <= '0';
        END IF;
        DigitalOutTemp(3) <='1';
        OutTemp(3) <= '1';          
        Next_state <= S_THREE;

    ELSIF (Current_state = S_THREE) THEN
        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN 
            DigitalOutTemp(3) <= '0';
            OutTemp(3) <= '0';
        END IF;
        DigitalOutTemp(2) <='1';
        OutTemp(2) <= '1';          
        Next_state <= S_TWO;

    ELSIF (Current_state = S_TWO) THEN
        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN 
            DigitalOutTemp(2) <= '0';
            OutTemp(2) <= '0';
        END IF;
        DigitalOutTemp(1) <='1';    
        OutTemp(1) <= '1';      
        Next_state <= S_ONE;

    ELSIF (Current_state = S_ONE) THEN
        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN 
            DigitalOutTemp(1) <= '0';
            OutTemp(1) <= '0';
        END IF;
        DigitalOutTemp(0) <='1';
        OutTemp(0) <= '1';          
        Next_state <= S_LSB;

    ELSIF (Current_state = S_LSB) THEN
        IF (Comparator = '0') THEN
            DigitalOutTemp(0) <= '0';
            OutTemp(0) <= '0';
        END IF;

        DigitalOutFinal <= OutTemp;

        DigitalOutTemp <= "10000000000000";
        OutTemp <= "10000000000000";

        Next_state <= S_MSB;

    END IF;
END PROCESS;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell what your code is trying to accomplish, so I thought I'd make some general observations that might help you along.

There is a lot of needless repetition in your code that you can fix by using a counter to index your bits rather than a hard coded index in each state, for example using a counter `idx` that counts from your MSB to LSB you can do:

```
...

elsif (current_state = COMPARE) then

  OutTemp(idx)     <= comparator;

  if idx > 0 then
    OutTemp(idx-1) <= '1';
    idx            <= idx - 1;
    next_state     <= current_state;
  else
    idx            <= MSB;
    next_state     <= idle;
  end if;
end if;
```

This assumes you want to set `OutTemp(idx-1)` in the previous state, which strikes me as a bit pointless, but maybe its required by your external hardware...

You have also duplicated your `OutTemp` by assigning to both a signal and a port, I would remove all your assignments to the port `DigitalOutTemp` and instead add the following to your clocked process:

```
process (clock)
begin

  if rising_edge(clock) then      
    Current_state <= Next_state;
    DigitalOutTemp <= OutTemp;
  end if;
end process;
```

This will set `DigitalOutTemp` synchronously, if you dont want this you can set it outside of the clocked process instead, but I would advise you to set it synchronously to avoid glitches.

To answer your question, the final state:

```
    ELSIF (Current_state = S_LSB) THEN
      IF (Comparator = '0') THEN
          DigitalOutTemp(0) <= '0';
          OutTemp(0) <= '0';
      END IF;

      DigitalOutFinal <= OutTemp;

      DigitalOutTemp <= "10000000000000";
      OutTemp <= "10000000000000";

      Next_state <= S_MSB;

    END IF;
```

.. will just set `DigitalOutTemp` to "`10000000000000"` and `DigitalOutFinal` to whatever was in `OutTemp` in the previous state. It appears that you expect `OutTemp` to have been updated by the assignment to `OutTemp(0)` further up, but this wont be the case. The assignment to `OutTemp(0)` is *scheduled* for the end of the process; it isn't visible immediately.

The assignments to `OutTemp(0)` and `DigitalOutTemp(0)` in the IF statement will do nothing as their scheduled writes are cancelled by your assignments to them further down.

So to answer your question, it looks like valid code in that it will probably compile and synthesize, but it wont exhibit the behaviour you seem to expect.

Hope this helps.